# how to update class file after restart tomcat

Tags: java, class, tomcat

I have changed a few java file, and replace the file in tomcat\webapps\program\WEB-INF\classes. After i restart the tomcat, supposedly the tomcat will auto-compiled java file and update the class file right? But why my class file does not update? I already set the **reloadable="true"** in server.xml

```html
<Context docBase="Book" path="\Book" reloadable="true"
```

Appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Maybe your assumption is wrong?

Comment: Did you replace the file then restarted the tomcat ? if so the operation should work successfully.

Comment: I would suggest stop tomcat --> update the class files --> start tomcat

Comment: I already checked, the date of class file not the latest one. Means that the class still not update. I am using tomcat 8,  in case this could be the reason it didn't work?

Comment: Are you adding the .java file to WEB-INF\classes and expecting Tomcat to compile it? That won't happen. You need to compile the java separately and replace the .class file in WEB-INF\classes.

Comment: But previously i'm using tomcat 5, the .java file can be compile and automatically update the .class file once i restart the tomcat

Comment: what IDE are you using for development  ?

Comment: im using eclipse

Comment: Cool, now you need to change your target(Classes) location to tomcat  WEB-INF\classes and need to start tomcat with command "catalina.bat jpda run" it will help you to set remote debug and also update class file in tomcat at runtime, If you need more info let me know

Comment: how to start tomcat with command "catalina.bat jpda run" ? i don't really understand on how to do it.

Comment: let your eclipse compile the classes for you, tomcat do not compile them, just as mentioned before set the server in your eclipse to target the new tomcat server and publish your project to your server then start/stop-start your server it will work.

Comment: @abc please refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting **autoDeploy=true** in **server.xml**. This way you may not need to restart the tomcat. Ideally useful for scenarios when you want to perform a hot deployment.

Comment: Try packaging your class files into a WAR. And then instead of updating class files directly in the WEB-INF\classes folder replace the older WAR with a new WAR that contains newer classes.

Answer (score 0):

To drop class file on tomacat at run time follow below procedure -

Eclipse -

> Go to your project right click -> Build Path-> Configure Build Path ->
>   click on Source Tab here -> Set Default output folder -> Click Bowse
>   -> Create New Folder -> give your folderName and click on Advance -> Check on link folder in file system -> Browse  and select
>   "WEB-INF\classes path"

This enable you to drop compile classes in tomcat context.

Tomcat -

> Go to tomcat bin folder -> open command prompt there and type
>   catalina.bat jpda run this will start your tomcat.

Now if you want to debug remotly

> Go to eclipse project right click -> Debug Ad ->Debug configuration ->
>   double click Remote Java application and click on debug button.

I hope that will help you.

Comment: still not working. is there any other way besides from using eclipse?

Comment: you can drirectly copy paste classes file in context